# C# - Cant convert var to List

Tags: c#, list

This code snippet returns me an error,

```
public List<auto> autoSelect()
{
       return autoSelect(DateTime.Today);
}
public List<auto> autoSelect(DateTime date)
{
       var onderhoudAuto = (from onderhoud in db.onderhouds 
                            where onderhoud.uitvoerdatum != DateTime.Today 
                            select onderhoud)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
       List<string> autos = (from auto in db.autos 
                             where auto.autoId.Equals(onderhoudAuto) 
                             select auto)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
       return autos;
}
```

I tried convert the var to  a list with `.ToList();` although this doesn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Of what type is `db.onderhouds`?

Comment: You declare the method _autoSelect_ to return a list of _auto_ but you try to return a list of _string_ Of course this is not accepted by a C# compiler

Comment: Putting everything in a single line makes the code unreadable. You didn't post any error so it's impossible to guess what's wrong, and very hard to read the code to see what may be the problem

Comment: Please include the error you're getting in the question

Comment: After cleaning up the code at least one compilation problem is obvious - the second query returns a single `auto` but tries to store it in a `List<string>` variable. Even if `auto` is a `string`, you'd be trying to assign a `string` to a `List<string>`

Comment: Even if you get that code to compile it would be extremely inefficient. You're executing 2 queries instead of one. The first only servers to load an ID that's used in the second query. In SQL you'd use a join, not two separate queries for this. When using EF Core you wouldn't use JOINs, you'd use LINQ to filter the objects and let LINQ to generate the JOINs based on the relations between the objects, eg `from auto in db.Autos where auto.Maintenance.All(m=>m.Date!=DateTime.Today) select auto`. Or should that be `m.Date==DateTime.Today` ?

Answer (score 2):

> I tried convert the var to a list

No, you do not. `var` is not actually a data type - it is resolved by the compiler. A tooltip should show you the real type.

Your problem is different:

Looking at your code, we can see:

The method `autoSelect` signature states that the return type is `List<auto>`

```cs
public List<auto> autoSelect(DateTime date)
```

The variable `autos` type is `List<string>`

```cs
List<string> autos = [...etc...]
return autos;
```

You return `autos`, but it is not possible to return a `List<string>` when a `List<auto>` is expected.

So it has nothing to do with `var` - it is simply you selecting as single property and returning a list of strings, but that is not the type the method is supposed to return.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `FirstOrDefault()` after your linq query, you are saying you want the first element (or the default -usually `null`- for the datatype if none matches) in the LINQ query, not a list of elements.

If you want a list of elements, use `ToList()` *on the linq query*, not try to convert a single entity to a list.

If you, for some reason, want a list of a single entity, then create a list (with `new List<type>()`) and then add your entity (of the same type as your list) to the list.